# Rewrite uppercase URLs to lowercase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

The requirement is to convert uppercase to lowercase url So I got this code,

my url = http://website.com/songs-mp3-download.html

i added

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

in httpd.conf file 
and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

in .htaccess ,, there is some error ,, while i try to search it returns to homepage..

if there is any php option i welcome

Comment: Can you see the error in the httpd server's `error_log` file?

Comment: no, it runs well , while i am search it return to homepage

Comment: Well, you defined the map name as `lc` but you're referring to it as `lowercase`, for one thing.. :-)

Comment: @RoUS is right. You need: `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]`

Comment: @anubhava `^/?` is ambiguous on `.htaccess` for `RewriteRule` ;)